The vertiginous question: Why am I me and not someone else?
From Wikipedia:

Benj Hellie's vertiginous question asks why, of all the subjects of experience out there, this one—the one corresponding to the human being referred to as Benj Hellie—is the one whose experiences are live? (The reader is supposed to substitute their own case for Hellie's.)

Basically, this question, if I am to understand it correctly, is asking that given the fact that there are many conscious individuals that exist, and given that I am one of these conscious individuals, how, and more importantly why, am I this particular conscious individual who has his lifespan in this era of the world and human history and who was born in that particular point in spacetime (when referring to the date and place of my conception)?
Some people like to be smart-alecks about this and state that it is a tautology, rephrasing the question into ‘Why is Alice Alice?’ and then answering the question as so: ‘Because if Alice wasn’t Alice she’d be someone else.’
Obviously the question is much more sophisticated than that, and is one of the greatest philosophical questions one can possibly ask, touching the intersection of philosophy of consciousness, metaphysics, and the soul among other things.
So I was wondering if there have been any serious discussions about this question, which give it the importance it deserves.

"the question is much more sophisticated than that" - well, that's debatable. Why is blue not green? Why is a horse not a chair? It reads like a nonsensical question wrapped up in moderate-big words to make it sound insightful, which you might expect to debate at 3 AM after taking way too many mind-altering substances. I have no idea what that's supposed to even be asking (once you scratch below the surface of "why is thing not not-thing") or how that relates to what's actually true. There are also a bunch of theories of mind, and each of those have different views of what consciousness is.

If you are not you, then you are someone else. Thus, someone else is you and he then asks who he is, and so???

"Why am I me?" is, in other words, asking, "Why is (the person designated by 'I') the same as (the person designated by 'me')?" But grammatically, these two terms obviously designate the same person. So there is no mystery why the answer would be in the affirmative.

Kant once talked about this potentially crucial vertiginous question using his term as transcendental reflection which you may study further...

Maybe the original paper has some more details... as written, it seems a typical "conundrum" disguised as a philosophical proble. We have a topic called Personal Identity, but saying "Why I am me...?" assumes that there is an "I" reflecting on himself.

The only way I can think of that "Why am I me?" wouldn't just be a tautology, is if you're really asking "Why is my soul in my body?" However, this question is only meaningful if you presuppose that you have a soul independent of your body, which you don't.

List proposes the many-worlds theory of consciousness designed to make sense of and answer the question. It requires reifying a multitude "first-personal worlds" in addition to the shared "third-personal" one:"Given the indexical nature of the question, any answer must point to a fact that isn't purely third-personal. If the locus of my conscious experiences is my first-personally centred world, then I am able to point to such a fact. There is a first-personal fact that holds at my first-personally centred world..."

Consider looking in to Nonduality.

The question assumes that we are not all the same 'mind', ie that there is one specific 'mind' for each specific human body. But maybe we all share the same mind... ?

A much stronger version of the inegalitarian perspective (vide @MauroALLEGRANZA 's answer) is Douglas Hardings's On having no head

I'm not sure I understand the question. Why is any person's experiences live? Who, may I ask, is the author of this question? The Wikipage is a stub.

@NotThatGuy ^this... I am surprised at how wrapped up in barely non-trivial explorations one can become when couched in previous "rigor" and verbiage. I picked up "great thinkers" from an estate sale (pub circa 196x?) and was shocked at the near futile mental meanderings of two of the great thinkers that were saints. That being said, I still think it is a useful question. Its just not that deep in comparison to the breadth of thought we have to stand on. Its sort of like the question about the branch falling in the forest. It is good beginnings. Lets encourage this.

Poem - I am not I

Perhaps, the status of each individual is leak proof even in the face of intercommunication - one can never bleed into another.

"one of the greatest philosophical questions one can possibly ask" Nope, it's a banal circular question. The question mentions this tautology, but then for an unstated reason makes the assumption that it "must" be more than that. It really isn't.

God knows. || If that seems ONLY a smart alec response then considering why whoever you are considers it so may be useful. Or not.

This is pure nonsense. I know that claim gets thrown around a lot when it comes to philosophy, but this is a prime example of navel gazing.

@ScottRowe Your Spanish poem reminds me towards this Polish one

Duplicate of https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/40458/why-am-i-myself-rather-than-someone-else ?

This question is arising, or more importantly, vexing you, because you have wrong ideas and you have fixated on them. The notion of a persisting separate self was debunked long ago, not only by the Buddha, and has been called in to question as long as humans have existed.
Children usually don't have this question, because they are busy doing what they do and not pondering. Older people usually brush it aside also because it leads nowhere. It is like pausing in a doorway and asking why you are in this particular doorway? Walk on!
Meditation is a good way to begin dissolving delusions about self. It has been proven for thousands of years. Eventually, many people see Nonduality which allows for knowing these sorts of things. It works.
Anecdote: I was driving on a freeway one time about 30 years ago, heading towards an underpass where I would go under a bridge of a large road. I saw all the cars on the bridge, but also a man jogging across... Time slowed, his strides slowed to a drumbeat, and I thought, "He has a life, too." The realization struck me with such force that tears came to my eyes and I nearly lost control of the car. All I could think for the next couple minutes was, he has a life, too.
These days, I often become aware of this when I see someone walking across the street ahead, or in a restaurant, on a plane, from an office window... Their life is as present and complete for them as mine is to me. When I walk in a cemetery on breaks from work, I see all these names of people with entire lives before my grandparents were even born.
Think of 100 billion humans who have lived, and half died from mosquito borne illnesses. Think what you can do with your dash. "Don't waste your time greeting people!"

You get a +1 for para 1 and a +1 for  para 3 and a -1 for para 2 (so adds up to +1 ). This question may in some sense lead nowhere but asking it is likely one of the shorter routes to non-duality often expressed as the formula: Who am I? If you like you could frame it in more detail as What about me is essentially me, and what about me is merely coincidence, happenstance like the shirt I happen to be wearing right now? The non dual master Nisargadatta was wont to say that our thoughts are as external to us as the things in the world. In fact even more so!!

@Rushi sure, asking the question inwardly is great, but asking someone else is like beginning a phone call by saying, "Is this the person to whom I am speaking?"

True that. But for starters starting by asking others and then have someone suggest You need to address this in 'solitary confinement' seems like a line of progress. My real point I guess is a bit different: the physicalist answers to this question are egregiously inconsistent. If the nondualist also answers dismissively, the questioner could well dismiss the question as worthless.  That would be unfortunate...

Thought I'd +1-ed. Evidently not. Heh!!  I guess I got derailed by Chris Degnen's answer which is really good.  (To me) there are only two reasonable directions to answer this question: Buddhist and Vedantic. Buddhist: There is no such thing as self. Vedantic: Other than the self there is nothing (no-thing).

@Rushi any thoughts on the part I added? Does it counter the 'dismissive' tone? Thanks.

What's the last sentence into  quotes? Rest I can resonate.

@rushi it's from an old story I can't place right now, about a man who travelled through a lot of hardship to meet two sadhus. He found them in meditation and waited patiently, then when one acknowledged him, he told his story of what he had gone through to find them.

+1 "Meditation is a good way to begin dissolving delusions about self." So is NaOH at 200 F which has the added benefit of being less mentally taxing.

@JD I had a college professor who said that the superego is soluble in alcohol. Might as well enjoy the dissolution, and, it is repeatable!

@ScottRowe Yeah, I'm stealing that, thanks.

Re "Children usually don't have this question, because they are busy doing what they do and not pondering.":  In fact, children have tones of questions. Maybe not so ontological ones, but still. Then, what you say here, renders philosophers --in fact, every thinking human being-- and thinking itself useless.  And also it contradicts yourself, because you are here thinking and talking about this very question. Wow, with one statement, you swept out everything!

@Apostolos "My work here is done!"

We may use SEP's entry reagarding Consciousness for general context.
More specifically, Hellie raises the "vertiginous question" in his review of  of David Chalmers, The Character of Consciousness (2010), where he rejects what he calls the "egalitarian stance":

"I trace this odd commitment to an egalitarian stance concerning the ontological status of personal perspectives—roughly, fundamental reality treats mine and yours as on a par. While egalitarianism is superficially quite plausible, the systematic theory of consciousness unfolding from it is besieged by objections from top to bottom. So if we judge egalitarianism by its fruits, it turns out to be extraordinarily implausible." [Note: I cannot find a source for "egalitarianism" wrt consciousness.]

We may consider at least Hellie's proposed answer to the question:

On the inegalitarian stance, only my stream of consciousness is genuine (read the first-person pronoun ‘sloppily’ rather than ‘strictly’, as referring to the reader rather than the writer). [...] The inegalitarian can answer the vertiginous question—or perhaps can explain why it shouldn’t be asked. Exactly one stream of consciousness is ‘live’; exactly one stream of consciousness is found in reality. So the question ‘why is this stream of consciousness (pointing to a bit of reality) the live one?’ gets the swift answer ‘it has no competition’. More emphatically: the only perspective on my stream of consciousness is my embedded perspective, and without two competing perspectives on my stream of consciousness, the vertiginous question can’t get asked. Why the premiss? The only stream of consciousness is mine and the only perspective from which consciousness is apparent is the embedded perspective from a stream of consciousness.


It's like asking why chocolate tastes good when I'm eating it but not when you are. I can understand this question as something one would encounter while becoming more self-aware, but not staying with it.

The first serious answer that is not dismissive. +1

I have one stream of consciousness in which I infer that others have one stream of consciousness. That is, I map a mind to each body and a body to each mind in my one stream of consciousness. I call this Unconscious Social Inference (USI). Mind-body dualism is conscious suspension of Unconscious Social Inference. I can consciously infer that a dead body, automaton, or philosophical zombie has no mind. The idea that my brain is in my body generating my mind; and your brain is in your body generating your mind; is coherent with my conscious recognition of living bodies, dead bodies, and USI.

@SystemTheory it can get interesting when one has multiple streams of consciousness. After that, it can feel like all the streams stop and there is just consciousness.

@ScottRowe - I know what feels like to be the guy who jumped on his horse and rode off in all directions! In the past I would often feel both the killing intensity of the predator and the terror of the prey. My mind often feels like it is operating on multiple levels of emotion and across several domains of knowledge simultaneously. But I don't experience multiple streams of consciousness. What happens is the distinction between self and not-self arises and passes away, but mostly, it arises, and it always arises in the social context where I assume others live inside their distinct reality.

OP: Why am I this particular conscious individual?
In one respect this question aims at a central mystery: the hard problem of consciousness, but in this case from consciousness's perspective where the OP wishes to know how his consciousness is connected to his body.
As Jo Wehler points out, consciousness initially has to learn to differentiate itself from its environment. (A task which when inadequately accomplished can cause splitting & projecting, whereby undesirable components of self are attributed elsewhere.)
So one learns that consciousness and body are paired.  However, to spell it out in steps that could be inspected leads to an impasse.
The connecting mechanism – from consciousness's perspective – is for the most part invisible, unconscious and only intuitive, so a detailed presentation of connection will not be forthcoming.  (In a similar way the place from wherever one's thoughts arise is also invisible.  To a certain extent thoughts can be deliberately formed, but the root source of thought is deeper and unseen.)
From the other perspective, that of biological and cognitive science, consciousness can be considered as an emergent mental activity but a detailed knowledge of what constitutes consciousness is lacking so we cannot trace all the steps from body to consciousness.
In some respects one's consciousness could be more general and transpersonal but in an important way it is localised by attachment to a specific body.
So, without being able to go into detail, you are this particular conscious individual because your consciousness and body are connected; the detail of the connection is a mystery.
Taking the question more broadly: why is one one's specific body?  Inspecting an indeterminate or infinite causal chain of procreation, evolution and cosmology is not going to yield a definite answer either.  The most determinate thing one can say is "I think therefore I am, and I'm connected to this specific body which I am too."  Or as Popeye would say "I yam 'cos I yam and that's what I yam!".

Or, as God would say, "I Am That I Am." The Abhidharma has a lot of details about how consciousness functions.

@ScottRowe One difference seems to be potentiality, for in Summa Theologiae St Aquinas says "Therefore, since in God there is no potentiality, as shown above (Article [1]), it follows that in Him essence does not differ from existence. Therefore His essence is His existence." Q. 3, A. 4. And in Being & Time Heidegger says "The essence of Dasein lies in its existence." GA 2, H. 42 i.e. Popeye's Dasein ...

but nevertheless observes that "In both ordinary and philosophical usage, Dasein, man's Being, is 'defined' as the ζῷον λόγον ἔχον (zóon lógon échon)—as that living thing whose Being is essentially determined by the potentiality for dis­course. 3" GA 2, H. 25


Normally a child learns to distinguish what belongs to his body and
what not. The latter is the seed for the concept of an external
world, while the first is the seed for the concept of “I”. Both
concepts are anchored as a dynamic data structure implemented in the
mental processes of the human brain.
The difference between you and me: Your concept of “I” is
implemented in your brain, while my concept of “I” is implemented in
my brain. From a first person view, you cannot experience my
datastructure while I cannot experience your datastructure.

For a relevant model from the philosophy of mind see Thomas Metzinger: Being No One. The Self-Model Theory of Subjectivity.

@andrós maybe it's more like asking why this pear is not another pear, which is pretty silly. Pears are probably asking themselves that all the time.

Both Mauro and Chris Degnen have good answers in the idealism direction.
Here is one more of the same vein.
Infant to Adult and back
Have you seen an infant grow up?
When we adults are in pain we say: “I am in pain!” Except when it becomes really painful and we reach the borders of consciousness and there are just screams, groans etc without mediating articulated language.
Likewise we express joy, anger, confusion... verbally. Or at most in actions.
For the infant it's unmediated by articulation, pure — gurgles, squeals, smiles, screams.
This is the first stage — pure consciousness.
Soon after, (6 months to a year) sounds start to be articulated which will later become:

Ma
Pa
milk (I want!)
cleaning (I need!)
etc

Let's say the infant's name is "Matt".
It will be noticed that he says "Ma" and "Pa" before he says "Matt".
And he says “Matt” for a while before learning to say “I”
In fact it is very striking to watch how the young 'un gets confused how "Matt and Pa" become "You and I" sometimes and "I and you" sometimes.
This we may call the beginning of individuation — somewhere along the way between age 2 and 4 typically.
This clearing out which happens typically between age 4 and 6 is what we may call "particularization".
Still, until about 10 the child lives in a "naturally magical world", not quite grokking that thoughts do not move external objects on their own.  We may call this a magical world because the child does not distinguish between my world and the common world.
When that distinction is confirmed, hardened and ossified we get an "adult" (so-called).
A few rare individuals (see Jung , Harding) find a way back in adulthood from the individualized, particularized thing-state to the pristine child state.
Most of the world's religions have a reference to that pristine state: Eden in Judeo-Christianity, Satya-yuga in Hinduism etc. 
And on rare occasions, found strewn across secular literature
— The great English poet Wordsworth remembers his childhood.
You may ask what this has to do with...
Your question

Why am I this particular conscious individual?

We assume that particularness and individuation are intrinsic and inherent in consciousness.  It is not so as a careful examination of the state near the "ends" (both birth and death) would show.
When we learn to separate consciousness from a particular individual we may be able to access the only answers that can (properly) address the question: the Buddhist and the Vedantic. They sound opposite but are really complementary.
Buddhist

There is no self. There may well be experience. But there is no being who experiences — anatta (actually an-atma)

Vedantic

There is only self — atma. The whole world is a film-show of maya. But in fact there are no people, events, story. Just the screen remaining ever unaffected by the play of light.

Independent support for inegalitarian view
Mauro's answer talks of the "inegalitarian view". Here are some more evidences for the inegalitarian, idealist viewpoint.
1. Language



Verb
Inf
1st
2nd
3rd




eat
to eat
I eat
you eat
he eats


sit
to sit
I sit
you sit
she sits


etc






is
to be
I am
you are
she is



So while many verbs in English are irregular, to be is specially irregular.
And this special irregularity of to be is found across languages. eg. In German it is:
verb: sein, Ich bin, Sie sind, Er ist
To me this suggests that from the distant past people have understood that "I am" is fundamentally different from "He is" "This table is" etc.
2. State of Deep Sleep
In the Vedantic teaching, the pinnacle is considered to be the Mandukya Upanishad which contains little more than a recitation of the three states of consciousness — waking, dream, and dreamless sleep, the implication being that one who has understood these has understood all that is to be understood.
So what is the big deal about these particularly deep sleep?
The question is usually formulated pithily as: How were you in deep sleep?
For the physicalist this is a trivial question with a trivial answer: I was lying on the bed, snoring.
For the idealist however this is a highly non-trivial question.
Because this does not work if consciousness is the root which generates the whole universe, and I was not conscious!
And yet we cannot say we don't exist because

A Matt does not wake up a Rushi (comes back to your question)
More significantly a really deep sleep has a sense of profound satisfaction without specific data, ie. memories: We know we exist(ed) but we cant say how. So this becomes an intimation of the child "pre-fall" state.


I have taught some adults programming, and some of them at first had the 'magical world' idea that just writing a function called UpdateDatabaseWhatever would make it happen. No, you have to write the code for that too. To be fair, computers now come with massive amounts of capability built in, and newcomers have to learn what to build, borrow or steal. I think today's children might be in for some unpleasant surprises if we have any significant infrastructure problems in the future. "I know the power is off, but why can't I Google what to do?"

@ScottRowe No that is not (what I call) magic. That is just a beginner not grokking the programming model. No different from beginner at violin makes ugly sounds, beginner at cycling falls down etc. I am using 'magic' much more literally. Children are quite simply closer to magic than we are. We have just forgotten what it was like 40,50,60 years ago. I guess in the Christian world it is expressed: Children are closer to God. In the Eastern world, especially nondual circles it could be Children are God

@ScottRowe One of the clearest recollections of the magic child-state as remembered by the English poet William Wordsworth.

There's a fundamental misunderstanding here. When we ask "How or why am I this particular conscious individual?", we feel like we're asking an ontological question, when in fact it's merely an epistemological one. I mean, if we were to ask the question "How or why am I living in this particular house", there's no real mystery. We built the house, or bought it, or rented it; we chose it from a selection of available houses for a variety of practical reasons. There's no mystery because we think of a house as something that belongs to us, not as a feature of who we are, and we can think and remember the various steps that brought it to us.
Identity is really just another house we live in. We built it up over our lifespan, with parts bought and paid for by our blood, sweat, joys, and tears… Of course, we can't pack up and move somewhere else like we can with a regular house (though we can remake ourselves, with effort), but that doesn't change the fact that identity is a construct: a thing we own, not a thing we are. If we ask "How or why am I this particular conscious individual?", the only real answer is that this particular conscious individual is the conscious individual we made for or of ourselves.

'Jack' is the house that Jack built, I guess. But, he can't take it with him.

>  Why am I me and not someone else?
It's the same question as why is it today and not Tuesday, May 7th, 1652?
Because you chose to ask the question today, not 400 years ago. Formerly speaking, the date was symmetric with respect to time until you chose a date to ask the question and asked it. Similarly:
You're you and not me because you're the one who asked that question. I didn't ask that question. YOU chose to ask it. That was your choice and your free will, and you can't reasonably act bewildered by that.
Read Nietzsche about responsibility and choice.

Yes, people seem to feel that asking a question automatically brings an answer in to being. Not so.

Downvoters, this is an answer, even if you don't like it. Taking responsibility for our thoughts is a vitally important first step. It's not very responsible to assume that everything already exists 'out there' and one can sit back and be a critic. It's a friggin' war!

@scott > It's a friggin' war! == Who are we fighting, Scott?

Time. No one is immune.

+1 for connecting "Why am I me?" with "Why is it now?"

I admit that this is a serious problem, but it does not mean that it is a complicated problem. In my opinion, the answer to this question is actually very simple: "I" is an "emergence," not an "arrival."
To put it simply, the "I" as the subject does not originally exist anywhere, whether it is heaven in the religious sense or the world in the practical sense. "I" is the result of a series of chemical reactions of matter that cannot be fully explained at present. "I" emerges from nothingness rather than being appointed by anyone to come into this world.
It's like a volcano erupting, it's underground molten rock that breaks through a weak patch of ground and spews out, rather than there being a hole there, molten rock chooses it.
Of course, this explanation is not entirely convincing, because we can't fully simulate chemical reactions to produce consciousness. If we can mass-produce fully self-aware robots in the future, the answer will be even more obvious.
Heidegger's philosophical system is amazing, but he sometimes makes some obvious mistakes. For example, he says that "people are pushed into the world," which gives the impression that the "I" originally existed somewhere like heaven or hell, and when the time was right, the "I" was propelled into the world by some mysterious force to begin a long (or very short) life.
This is actually similar to the heaven theory or the reincarnation theory held by most religions in the world, but they all have a self-consistent question: Why did I come into this world as me and not someone else? Religious theories can, of course, explain that this is the will of God or the actions of people in previous lives. But how to read God's will? How can past life behavior be known? Therefore, we cannot bring these theories into the realm of rational thought because they are unknowable.
Therefore, I think that if chemical reactions at the physical level and theological logic at the religious level cannot explain the emergence of the "I", then we can explain it with the help of Schopenhauer's theory of will: in the long and vast space and time, blind will drives matter to carry out various physical movements and chemical reaction attempts, over and over again. At a certain point, the chemical reactions and physical movements of matter give rise to consciousness, and "I" emerges in the world as one of the representations of the will.

If I go the beach and pick up a grain of sand, one can ask two questions

What is the probability that, given the seemingly infinite number of grains of sand on this beach, that I picked this particular one?
What is the probability that I picked a grain of sand?

The answer to the first question is almost zero, the answer to the second question is one. The difference is that for the first question I attach special meaning to this particular grain of sand. 100s of thousands of people are born every day. One of them happened to be you. What is the probability that you are you, given that you are you?

Nonduality brings these two questions together with the experience of 'particularity'.

A physicalist (reductive materialist) answer is that your consciousness reduces to what happens in your brain, and that ends up the way it does because of genes and environmental conditions.
So a particular "you" can't be a different "you" if you have the same genes and you were exposed to the same environment that resulted in the same brain development. And you would have been a different you if you had different genes or if you were exposed to a different environment.
If you lightly hit your head on something, that would make you a different you, although it would be much like the current you, except with a slightly sore head. More generally, who you are is constantly changing as you experience things and think about things, and as your brain and body develops and ages naturally, and as things physically happen to your brain and body, even if those changes are (typically) fairly small on a moment-to-moment basis.

And no one likes a sorehead :-) So are you basically saying that the person asking the question wouldn't even be that particular person and the question might have been felt differently if things had been slightly different? I think this would be the rational basis for understanding the Buddha's non-self assertion. It is simply an incoherent, unexamined belief that many people have.

Re "The vertiginous question: Why am I me and not someone else?"
I can't see anything vertiginous in this. Neither that is a question that stands out from all other philosophical questions (Re: "the")
There are dozens of similar questions we frequently come upon, of the sort "Why something instead of nothing?".
I call this kind of questions "empty", i.e. they are devoid of any meaning and purpose. Some of them are also circular, like the present one: If I were someone else, I would ask myself again "Why I am me and not someone else?" ... Ad infinitum.
These questions are also characterized by this: they can accept a simple, obvious and indisputable answer, of the type: Because it couldn't be otherwise!.

Q: Why am I me and not someone else?
A: Because you are not someone else!
(or, simply, Because you are you!)
Q: Why is this an apple?
A: Because this is what it is, (an apple!")

All these responses --apparently naive "truisms"-- answer the question fully, don't they? And they are naive because the question is too and deserves such responses. And if we try to question them, we will inevitably get into a circularity, as I indicated in the beginning.
Now, there may be also an ontological aspect about this question --as some have pointed out in their answers-- which could make it somewhat more interesting. And that would certainly have to do with the concept of self. A subject that is so much discussed in philosophy ... However, I believe that taking this up will only lead away of the spirit of the topic as I sense it.

"Why is there something instead of nothing" does not fall in this class, nor in any other properly. It is THE ultimate question. I suggest that you choose another example :-).

para 3: You mix up circular with idempotent

(To @Russell McMahon) Well, it is certainly not the same thing with the question of the topic, but it is in the same spirit and has a lot of common attributes with it:. (If you read my whole message you will see that all the things I said apply to it too. )

(To @Rushi)  The term "idempotent" is mainly applied to math and computer science, not to philosophy. And it refers to the repetition of the same thing ("idem"). However, you are right to spot "circularity". It may not be the correct term --"circular reasoning" would be more correct-- but its essence,  --what I actually mean, the element of circularity-- is involved anyway. Besides, that's why I'm giving examples ...

Circularity is when you define a in terms of a. Idempotence is when a... works out to a. Classic example: a = a × 1. When you use it to simplify a × 1 to a it  is mighty useful. If you use it to spin out a = a × 1 = a × 1 × 1 = a × 1 × 1 × 1... then not so much. You are demonstrating that spin-out and calling it circularity. No your examples dont demonstrate circularity; they just demonstrate the non-useful use of spin-out/idempotence

OK, I undestand what you say.

Great that you see that. Cheers!!

It would also great if you saw too what I'm telling in my answer to the topic!

Your answer trivializes and effectively ridicules the question. This is quite the norm for the view from the materialist/naturalist pov. This comment and still more it's upvotes speak for this pov. Putting aside labels like "materialist/idealist" etc, if you see my answer, it makes the case that this is a highly non trivial question.

I've reformatted for better readability. Revert or change as you like. And where I've said "materialist/naturalist" above I should have said more appropriately "(logical) positivist"


given the fact that there are many conscious individuals that exist, and given that I am one of these conscious individuals, how, and more importantly why, am I this particular conscious individual who has his lifespan in this era of the world and human history and who was born in that particular point in spacetime (when referring to the date and place of my conception)?

This question is much more trivial than you make it out to be. The answer is both logical and empirical.
First, the law of identity says that every thing is itself. If this law is true, then there is simply no logical possibility that you could be something not yourself, whatever that is.
Second, the question assumes something which makes no sense, namely that being someone is a totally improbable coincidence between one pre-existing consciousness among zillions of others, and one pre-determined body among zillions of others. This is delusion on a massive scale. We have zero idea as to what is consciousness beyond our experience of it, but whatever it is is irrelevant. What matters are our ideas, because, as we can all verify for ourselves, we are only conscious of our own ideas and nothing else. However, our ideas all rather obviously are the result of our personal experience of the real world, one which we acquire through our own sensory perception, which is itself a property of our own body. Each of us has only one body and consequently a unique vantage point from which to look at the real world because our body is unique. Bodies are unique because there is an exclusion principle à la Pauli: Not two human bodies can occupy the same region of space at the same time. Thus, we go through life developing a unique perspective, a unique set of ideas, a unique set of memories, and all along, at each instant, we can only have a unique experience of life because we experience every moment in the context of our own past experience. Thus, the uniqueness of our ideas, and therefore of the consciousness we have of our idea, is hardwired into the materiality of our body.
Such is life.

Because he's the one asking the question.

So why is Matt Harper he and not someone else? (now I'm asking you the question about him)

@ScottRowe : there is no "someone else". You only have the perception of "him" (or anything, for the matter!) as they are, as opposed to anything that could ever be! You're asking why some (arbitrary-defined) blobs, in this case a human-shaped blob, inside the infinite messy soup that is reality (as it appears from your perspective) the way you perceive them. I dunno man, you're the one seeing them, not me.

Jean: So you're answering without seeing (perceiving) a questioner? Two actually Matt, @ScottRowe. Or 3 if you add me!! The plural diversity of the world just may be erased in sleep, coma, drugs or deep meditation. But it cannot easily be transferred out of those states. Or as I argued with Scott below his answer the q may lead nowhere, but it's not a trivial question

Because you are the result of your body plus enviornment and circumstances, and not a separate entity that might be attached to just any old body.
You have characteristics that are a direct result of your genetic composition.
You are "your body/brain/etc".  Not removable from your hosting brain.  A product of it.
Which is why you are you, not another.

If you are the result of your body and your environment, the what are you? You cannot have a body and also be your body at the same time, can you?
If you have something, you are the owner of that something.
You are separate and different from that something, aren't you?

I have a left arm.  I would never claim I am my left arm.  I have a body.  A brain.  Nerves.  The patterns they are in... result in a me that has awareness (when I aint sleeping), and makes choices based on past memories, experiences, and incoming sensory information.  That's "me".

If I understand this well, you are still saying that you are the result of your body.  Aren't you? What I asked was, what is this "you"? If this "you" is affected by the body and the environment, if this "you" has awareness, as you say, then this "you" is something different from all that, isn't it? So, it must be something else. What is it?

@apostolos Yes, I would say... result of genes, nutrition, and the nurturing, education, and experiences and opportunities one has to grow, develop, absorb insights and info and tastes, and info driven cautions and wants.  We are "that" the sum of developed memories, and plans and tastes... only our path through life can have provided those things... we didn't bring "20 years if experience in the IT industry" with us from elsewhere... we made it ourselves with our presence.  And those years made us who we were at the end of the 20, what we had become capable of.

That's what I would consider "me".  My collected memories, conclusions, etc.  My "id" within my biological meatsack is hosted and has been built by "me" and my meatsack over a period of almost 62 years.  We always travel as a pair, and unlike Supe and Clark, me and my meatsack are only ever seen in the same room, together.



The vertiginous question fails the most basic requirements of the observation-selection effect
Personally, I don't find this question to be particularly vexing.  To me it appears to be easily answered by a variant of the "observation-selection effects" examined by the philosopher Nick Bostrom in his formulation of the anthropic principle (also called the observation-selection effect).  The most general form of the observation-selection effect is a simple manifestation of the rules of conditional probability --- it says that the range of possible observations you may make about the universe is limited by the relevant conditional information, including the fact that you are here and asking the question at issue.
The vertiginous question represents a failure of conditional reasoning, insofar as it refuses to condition on the observation-selection effect --- that you are here asking why you are you and not someone else instead.  This is an example of the "stolen concept fallacy" whereby the observer asks for a causal explanation of a conditioning fact that is a requirement of their presence asking the question.  When an observer asks "why" this conditioning state is extant, the answer is that if the conditioning state was not extant then they would not be here to ask the question.  Thus, the question at issue implies the necessity of the state for which they seek an explanation.
The vertiginous question treats your consciousness as if it were a free-floating thing that could manifest randomly as the consciousness of any conscious being.  The philosopher David Chalmers points out that this is an "egalitarian" stance that treats the consciousness of the observer as being on par with the (inferred) consciousness of others.  In doing so, the vertiginous question gets things backwards epistemologically.  It begins with the observation that there are many conscious being and then presents your own consciousness as some mystery to be solved.  But in fact, it is the fact that you are conscious that lets you observe the world and conclude (on the basis of inductive reasoning) that there are other conscious beings at all.  You are taking your own consciousness for granted in deciding that your inference of the existence of other conscious beings is valid.

The question is not a particularly useful one, provided one assumes that each self is unitary, and out of communication with other selves.
IF those presuppositions hold, THEN each one of us will be a unique self.  If one adds in materialism/physicalism, then why you are "THIS" particular unique self -- has no answer.  One will be SOME unique self, so why not THIS one?
But question the presuppositions, and then more options appear.
Assume that we are not a solitary unique self, and the possibility of superposition of multiple selves, whose memories are all identical up to a point, but then diverge, becomes possible.  This concept is assumed in Everettian quantum universe-spitting, as an example of a physicalist worldview that embraces it.
Spiritual dualists often accept the existence of spiritual attachments, who carry along with a self as the self lives its life. Upon death, the attachments may separate from the core self, and then both with encountered can relate the same memory. Also, if a self is multiple not unitary, there can be IDENTICAL selves that are prepositioned during life, then split and live different lives post-death.  Past life reincarnation therapists have encountered multiple patients who relate the same past life memory, and have resorted to either attachments, or superposition hypotheses to make sense of their patient's past lives.
Why one is "this" me, is still unclear from these POVs.  Karma theories are an attempt to provide a further explanation.
Assume we are not actually independent identities, and instead blend into each other and the nature of selfhood gets very fuzzy.
The most clearly articulated versions of this are from the non-duality advocates, who hold that we are not actually a "me", that selfhood is a delusion.  This is a core concept of much of Buddhism, of parts of Hinduism, and of the Perennial Philosophy.
From a materialist perspective Hume also argued that there is no self -- that "me-ness" is a delusion.  So it is not just idealists or spiritualists who make this claim.
From the POV of non-duality, or of Humean "no-self", your question is nonsensical, and a result of succumbing to the delusion of selfhood.

I don't think that Buddhist non-self is a form of Idealism, more like anti-Idealism. Also, non-self doesn't mean that everyone is connected, or one entity.

@ScottRowe in the Perennial philosophy, sihkism and the Hindus who hold by it, our delusion is that we are different from God.

That delusion is delusional :-) :-( .

I believe you are getting trapped in a polysemy around "idealism" @ScottRowe. In its everyday usage it connotes being unrealistic, a dreamer, not grounded etc. In its philosophical usage it is a generic anti-materialist position of making ideas/ideation or more easternly, consciousness, more foundational than matter

Dcleve: I feel you should factorize this answer along 2/3 branches: For materialist, For dualist, For non-dualist. Otherwise your 1st bolded paragraph becomes your consolidated summary position

@Rushi I was speaking of Buddhism as not being a religion, not concepts or ideas or ideals or anything else that we can speak about. It is about not speaking. Yes?

Well... I'm not so sure @ScottRowe... Dunno in what tone of voice you speak. Eg. You can find many westerners (on Buddhism SE) who dispute that Buddha taught karma. There may well be a sense in which this can be justified; But almost certainly not the sense in which the westerner wishes to push and cherrypick.
